# Avoid 2 textview to overlap

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, overlap

I have two Textviews in a card, To set the Title and hours. Until now, all was working perfect, because the titles where so short, but now, I'm having long titles.

To avoid that the card expands with the title I set the `ellipse` attribute.

But the problem is that the two textviews are overlaping, and I don't know how to solve it.

[image]

The code:

```
        <com.gc.materialdesign.views.Card
            android:id="@+id/jir_card_headerissue"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/jir_issue_name_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/inner_components_spacing"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Crear nueva vista"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/jir_acc_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/inner_components_spacing"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:text="20h"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

        </com.gc.materialdesign.views.Card>
```

Library used for the `Card`: https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary

Comment: Write it inside a **Horizontal LinearLayout with weights**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `Card` extends a `RelativeLayout` - you're actually taking advantage of this using attributes like `android:layout_centerVertical` or `android:layout_alignParentRight` as they wouldn't work in any other layout).

You can use it further and add a constraint for the long text view to be to the left of the short one. First you need to move the short one to be first in your layout, then add these attributes to the long one: `android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/jir_acc_time"`, `android:layout_toStartOf="@id/jir_acc_time"`, `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`, `android:layout_alignParentStart="true"`. Full example:

```
    <com.gc.materialdesign.views.Card
        android:id="@+id/jir_card_headerissue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jir_acc_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/inner_components_spacing"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:text="20h"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jir_issue_name_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/inner_components_spacing"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/jir_acc_time"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/jir_acc_time"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Crear nueva vista"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

    </com.gc.materialdesign.views.Card>
```

Comment: Worked perfect! :D Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can put 2 `TextView` to inside a `GroupLayout` to organize layouts (for example horizontal `LinearLayout`)

```
<com.gc.materialdesign.views.Card 
...>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/jir_issue_name_tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/inner_components_spacing"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Crear nueva vista"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/jir_acc_time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/inner_components_spacing"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:text="20h"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</LinearLayout>
</com.gc.materialdesign.views.Card>
```

Comment: `com.gc.materialdesign.views.Card` seems to be a `RelativeLayout` so you can achieve the same effect with additional constraints. No need to nest another layout.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using LinearLayout then use orientation Horizontal otherwise may be you are using Relative Layout then set alignLeft to other text view

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `TextViews` in `LinearLayout` using these attributes:

```
<com.gc.materialdesign.views.Card>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jir_issue_name_tv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/inner_components_spacing"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Crear nueva vista"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jir_acc_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/inner_components_spacing"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:text="20h"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

</LinearLayout>
</com.gc.materialdesign.views.Card>
```

Second textview will take needed space to show its text, while first textview will fill remaining space.

Comment: `com.gc.materialdesign.views.Card` seems to be a `RelativeLayout` so you can achieve the same effect with additional constraints. No need to nest another layout.

Comment: Sure for performance, but if layout is simple doesn't change and this is more intuitive in my opinion

Comment: Well, it's up to everybody to decide for themselves what is more intuitive for them, but for me nesting another layout, when you can just use the layout you already have, is not intuitive.